# Virtualbox Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_LDR_MISMATCH_NATIVE)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Computer got hard rebooted with an active guest and ever since I cannot get VB to work. Reinstall, uninstall, scrounge every VB file I can find on the hd and delete, clean update to new version. To be clear all guests, even new ones after the old ones have been completely destroyed, generate this error when I try to start them.

Windows 7, 64. using latest version of VirtualBox (only like a day old).

Here are some logs from log files I found. None of them seem particularly interesting.

> 00:49:14.833945          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={Machine} aText={Machine is not locked for session (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
>   00:49:21.780590          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={3295e6ce-b051-47b2-9514-2c588bfe7554} aComponent={ExtPackManager} aText={No extension pack by the name 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' was found}, preserve=false
>   00:49:21.851599          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={Saved screenshot data is not available (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false

---

> 00:47:41.904773 UIMediumEnumerator: Machine (or snapshot) event processed, ID = 5a8e9544-e6e0-49cf-8a80-3d6b5b3ab6d3
>   00:47:44.732378 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_UNEXPECTED (0x8000ffff) aIID={12f4dcdb-12b2-4ec1-b7cd-ddd9f6c5bf4d} aComponent={Session} aText={The session is not locked (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false
>   00:47:56.420284 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_UNEXPECTED (0x8000ffff) aIID={12f4dcdb-12b2-4ec1-b7cd-ddd9f6c5bf4d} aComponent={Session} aText={The session is not locked (session state: Unlocked)}, preserve=false